# Resetting Styles to Default in Microsoft Word 2008

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, office-for-mac, microsoft-word-2008

I want to reset all my MS-Word "Styles" to their default settings; i.e. fonts, sizes, spacing, etc. There doesn't seem to be an option to do this in the "Styles" panel. Is there any other way to do this?

I have attached an image of my "Style" page below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about for a particular document, you can use the organiser (Organiser... button from your screenshot) to copy styles between the style-set for the current document and the global defaults stored in `Normal.dotm`.

According to the article in the link below, the `Normal.dotm` must exist and when deleted, Office restores it. So to restore global defaults, the suggestion of deleting Normal.dotm seems like a logical solution. Simply:

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Microsoft/Office/User\ Templates/Normal.dotm
```

from the terminal works.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/i-accidentally-deleted-the-normaldotm-from-word/e5f7902f-2cba-496f-9b84-aa449d8e2863

Comment: Normal.dotm only has "Default Paragraph Font", "No List", "Normal", and "Table Normal".  It doesn't have headings, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not telling you this from experience, but internet research. See if you can find a file called "Normal" in Documents/Microsoft User Data. Deleting that should reset the default style.